# How do I pass Runnable objects to a Handler?

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable, handlers

I am learning via a book and it gives me this example:

```
Handler handler=new Handler() { 
    @Override 
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
        bar.incrementProgressBy(5); 
    } 
};
```

and

```
Thread background=new Thread(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
        try { 
            for (int i=0;i<20 && isRunning.get();i++) { 
                Thread.sleep(500); 
                handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage()); 
            } 
        } catch (Throwable t) { 
            // just end the background thread 
        } 
    } 
});
```

Which works out great. But, further down in the book it says:

> If you would rather not fuss with Message objects, you can also pass
>   Runnable objects to  the Handler, which will run those Runnable
>   objects on the activity UI thread. ...you can use those same methods
>   on any View (i.e., any widget or  container). This slightly simplifies
>   your code, in that you can then skip the Handler object.

But there are no examples given of how to do this via a `Runnable` object. Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
```

---

```
Thread background=new Thread(new Runnable() { 
          public void run() { 
            try { 
              for (int i=0;i<20 && isRunning.get();i++) { 
                Thread.sleep(500); 
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                    bar.incrementProgressBy(5);
                  }
                });
              } 
            } 
            catch (Throwable t) { 
              // just end the background thread 
            } 
          } 
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the example though, have selected your answer

Comment: You have two runnables, now. Therefore, you will have two run() methods. Not much we can do about it... (But some code structuring can make it look slightly nicer.)

Comment: Still looks a bit weird to me :)  As a person who is used to this (ie, not a noob like me)... is this a popular format for Android developers? Do you use something like this much in your code?

Comment: Nested classes are often used. `Runnable` in particular. I think it's more specific to Java (UI in particular) rather than Android.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the example and taking the time to answer my Qs. Cheers!

Comment: What does exactly mean that we can "skip the Handler object." using `Runnable`? Do not we need `Handler` object for passing `Runnable`?

Comment: @Joseph82: Maybe it's referring to what's written at the end of section 5.2 of this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html (I haven't tried it myself, just starting to learn Android programming.)

Answer (score 2):

As per the Android Docs for [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29):

> public final boolean post (Runnable r)
>
> Since: API Level 1 Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message
>   queue. The runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is
>   attached. Parameters
>
> r --  The Runnable that will be executed. Returns
>
> Returns true if the Runnable was successfully placed in to the message
>   queue. Returns false on failure, usually because the looper processing
>   the message queue is exiting.

Comment: Finding the definitions are pretty easy via a google or docs search. But for a noob like me those definitions could be explaining String Theory or rocket science, thats why I was asking if someone could post an example please? It's easier to understand after seeing the code and then matching it up to the definition.